# error: path does not exist in spark submit with hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

We are using the command `/home/ubuntu/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class "SimpleApp" /home/ubuntu/spark/examples/src/main/scala/sbt/target/scala-2.11/teste_2.11-1.0.jar` to run the script below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._


object SimpleApp {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {

     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("query1").master("yarn").getOrCreate
     val header = StructType(Array(
             StructField("medallion", StringType, true),
             StructField("hack_license", StringType, true),
             StructField("vendor_id", StringType, true),
             StructField("rate_code", IntegerType, true),
             StructField("store_and_fwd_flag", StringType, true),
             StructField("pickup_datetime", TimestampType, true),
             StructField("dropoff_datetime", TimestampType, true),
             StructField("passenger_count", IntegerType, true),
             StructField("trip_time_in_secs", IntegerType, true),
             StructField("trip_distance", FloatType, true),
             StructField("pickup_longitude", FloatType, true),
             StructField("pickup_latitude", FloatType, true),
             StructField("dropoff_longitude", FloatType, true),
             StructField("dropoff_latitude", FloatType, true),
             StructField("payment_type", StringType, true),
             StructField("fare_amount", FloatType, true),
             StructField("surcharge", FloatType, true),
             StructField("mta_tax", FloatType, true),
             StructField("trip_amount", FloatType, true),
             StructField("tolls_amount", FloatType, true),
             StructField("total_amount", FloatType, true),
             StructField("zone", StringType, true)))

     val nyct = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("header", "true").schema(header).load("/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv")
     nyct.createOrReplaceTempView("nyct_temp_table")

     spark.time(spark.sql("""SELECT zone, COUNT(*) AS accesses FROM nyct_temp_table WHERE (HOUR(dropoff_datetime) >= 8 AND HOUR(dropoff_datetime) <= 19) GROUP BY zone ORDER BY accesses DESC""").show())

     }
 }
```

The idea is run the query in the script into a cluster with spark and Hadoop. But in the end of the execution this generate a error to reed a csv file from path `/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv`. [This is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr44E.png)

I think the problem is that the node slave can't find the file in the master dir. Someone know how can i fix this and run this script in cluster?

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv` is a path of local filesystem and spark is trying to read from hdfs filesystem path `hdfs://master2:9000/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv`. so if you are reading from local filesystem, include `file:` in your path as `file:/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv` otherwise upload the file in hdfs in this directory `/home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running in cluster, you should have this file in hdfs. You can copy the files from local filesystem to HDFS using the following command:

```
hadoop fs -put source_path dest_path
```

Then use the dest_path in your code.

For you, do this on the host that has the local file:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/ubuntu/trip_data/trip_data_fare_1.csv <some_hdfs_location>
```

Verify that the copy has worked by doing the following:

```
hdfs dfs -ls <some_hdfs_location>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then Spark is considering your local file system as its default file system, that's why you are facing this error.The configurations should be passed into Spark context and you should mention the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in `spark-env.sh` file in all the nodes.Make sure the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is specified in all the nodes

```
val spCont = <Spark Context>
val config = spCont.hadoopConfiguration

config.addResource(new Path(s"${HADOOP_HOME}<path to core-site.xml>"))
```